# Video track doesn't have capabilities from Navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints()

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia, media-source, mediastream

I have video tag with a stream from the camera on the page and I want to change focusMode and focusDistance.

The problem is that I could see focusMode and focusDistance in navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints(), but I didn't see them then I try to get them and change from the actual video, like so:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then((stream) => handleSuccess(stream, canPlay))
      .catch(e => console.log(e))

function handleSuccess(stream, canPlay, video) {
  const video = document.getElementById('video');
  video.srcObject = stream
  const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
  track.getCapabilities() // doesn't return focusMode or focusDistance.
}
```

In general I want to do something like that:

```
function onCapabilitiesReady(capabilities) {
    if (!capabilities.focusDistance) {
      return;
    } else {
      track.applyConstraints({
        advanced : [{focusMode: "manual", focusDistance: 0.3}]
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API/Constraints)

> The process works like this (using MediaStreamTrack as an example):
>
> 1. If needed, call MediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints() to get the
>    list of supported constraints, which tells you what constrainable
>    properties the browser knows about. This isn't always necessary,
>    since any that aren't known will be ignored when you specify
>    them—but if you have any that you can't get by without, you can
>    start by checking to be sure they're on the list.
> 2. Once the script knows whether the property or properties it wishes to use are supported, it can then check the capabilities of the API
>    and its implementation by examining the object returned  the track's
>    getCapabilities() method; this object lists each supported constraint
>    and the values or range of values which are supported.
> 3. Finally, the track's applyConstraints() method is called to configure the API as desired by specifying the values or ranges of
>    values it wishes to use for any of the constrainable properties about
>    which it has a preference.
> 4. The track's getConstraints() method returns the set of constraints passed into the most recent call to applyConstraints().This may not
>    represent the actual current state of the track, due to properties
>    whose requested values had to be adjusted and because platform default
>    values aren't represented. For a complete representation of the
>    track's current configuration, use getSettings().
>
> In the Media Stream API, both MediaStream and MediaStreamTrack have
> constrainable properties.

`getSupportedConstraints()` returns the Constraints/Capabilities supported by your browser. But this doesn't necessarily means that your Camera/Webcam supports it. That is where the getCapabilties() comes in. Also note... to check the actual constraints you should be calling `.getSettings()`, because `.getConstraints()` will only fetch the custom/overwritten constraints.